# Sum a percentage in a double-precision column. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently I have a column in a table price with this value

```
4.5454...
5.4545...
10
```

And I want to update it with the current value + sum the 10%
So it becomes

```
5
6
11
```

How I can do this in postgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
update price
    set col = floor(col*1.1);
```

Perhaps you do not want the `floor()`, but your desired output looks to be integers.